# how to alert if the input date is greater than defined date in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am having an input date field in my form. In my date field
i need to alert an error if the input date is greater than any date i define before
here is what i code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date(2016,2,1); //the defined date is 1 March 2016
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    month = month + 1;

    if(day < 10){
        day = '0' + day;
    }

    if(month < 10){
        month='0'+month;
    }

    someday = day + '/' + month + '/' + date.getFullYear();

    $("#q1 input").blur(function(){   //#q1 is the ID for the input field.
        if($('#q1 input').val() > someday){
            alert('the input is bigger than the defined');
        }else{  
            alert('the defined is bigger than the input ');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If `q1` is id for input field, then I don't think you need to use `#q1 input` you can use `#q1` directly.

Comment: You can compare Date objects directly: `if (date0 > date1) {/* date0 is after date1 */`.

Answer (score 1):

To compare Dates is very straight forward. Most operators coerce the operands to number, and Dates return their time value so to see if today is before or after say 1 March 2016, create two Dates and compare them:

```js
var epoch = new Date(2016,2,1); // Create date for 2016-03-01T00:00:00
var now   = new Date();         // Create a date for the current instant
now.setHours(0,0,0,0);          // Set time to 00:00:00.000

if (now < epoch) {
  alert('Before 1 March, 2016');
} else {
  alert('On or after 1 March, 2016');
}
```

Or a bit more compact:

```
alert((now < epoch? 'Before':'On or after') + ' 1 March, 2016');
```

Comment: it is ok if i want to compare between the current date (now) and the defined date. but the problem i facing is that i have input field in my form it's type is text so date inside this field is string format , any way to convert it to date then compare between two dates ?

Comment: @M.Gooda—see the accepted answer to [*javascript Date.parse*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse/2587398#2587398).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compare the values as in the date form, not the way you did.
Convert the input value into the form of date and compare it with the variable 'date'.

Comment: i know that the reason of problem is comparing string format with date format  but what i do not know how to convert string to date format to compare between them.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the input date with the desired date that you defined. For example:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(d1);
var same = d1.getTime() === d2.getTime();
var notSame = d1.getTime() !== d2.getTime();
```

If you find it tricky, then there is an awesome js library called [moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com).  It is very useful when playing with dates.

Comment: To determine if *d1* is before *d2* is not tricky: `if (d1 < d2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date=new Date(2016,2,1); //the defined date is 1 March 2016
    var fixedDate = returnDate(date);// convert date in dd/mm/yyyy format
 
    //#q1 input will search a child input inside an #q1 dom element, which probably not the case
    // input#q1 will refer to input with id #q1
   // You can directly query the input since it has id #q1 so #q1 input is not correct


$("#q1").blur(function(){   //#q1 is the ID for the input field.
 var d2 = new Date($('#q1').val());
 var inputDate = returnDate(d2); // convert input date in dd/mm/yyyy format

 if(inputDate > fixedDate){ // compare two dates
  console.log('the input is bigger than the defined');
  }else{    
  console.log('the defined is bigger than the input ');
}
});
});

// Write a general function to convert date in dd/mm/yyyy format
function returnDate(date){
   var day=date.getDate();
    var month=date.getMonth();
    month=month+1;
    if(day<10){
    day='0'+day;
 }
   if(month<10){
   month='0'+month;
 }
 var someday=day+ '/' + month + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  return someday;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/d24ftn54/)

**EDIT 1**

Use ternary operator instead of `if-else`

```
inputDate > fixedDate? (console.log("the input is bigger than the defined")):(console.log("the defined is bigger than the input"))
```

[with ternary operator](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/d24ftn54/1/)

Comment: This compares two strings, not two dates so any date string with a bigger day than any other date string will be "bigger", regardless of month or year.

Comment: Exactly, but how to convert the string format to date format to compare between them